# Volume by shell method

Tags: calculus

I've been having trouble solving for the volume of a solid of revolution of the equation $y = x^2$, bounded by $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, revolved around $y = -2$.

My equation becomes Integral from 0 to 1 of: $\int_{0}^{1}2\pi(y+2)(\sqrt{y}) dy$ by

Solving for that gives me $\frac{52\pi} {15}$.

However the answer I'm given is 23pi/15 and I'm extremely confused as to where I went wrong. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The "height" of the cylindrical shell at $y$ is $1-\sqrt{y}$. You may be rotating the wrong region. It is below $y=x^2$, to the left of $x=1$, and above the $x$-axis.